# Can the Jquery.ui slider handles be labled? i.e. << or >>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to decorate the slider handles with text or images?
I would like to differentiate the high and low handles on a range slider configuration.

Comment: Yes it is possible, however i don't have any suggestions on how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MFNpD/)** that uses text for one handle and an image for the other.

Basically you can use the slider's [create method](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-create) to alter the handles:

```
create: function() {
    $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(0)').text('<');
    $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(1)').append('<img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Sizicons/12x12/arrow_right_blue_round.png" />');
}
```